# About "touch base" and its usage

Tags: usage

I would like to inquire about the following points related to **"touch base"**:

1. Is "touch base" an idiom?
2. Is it formal or informal? For example, in a work environment when the boss say to his employee: `I would like to touch base with you`. In this case, is it formal or informal.
3. Can it be used convey good news or bad new? For example:

> The teacher would like to touch base with her students to reward him
>   or punish him.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [dictionary.cambridge.org](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/touch-base?topic=informal-talking-and-conversation), [collinsdictionary.com](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/touch-base) and [idioms.thefreedictionary.com](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/touch+base):

1. "Touch base (with someone)" **is an idiom**.
2. It is **Informal**.
3. I don't see any restriction for conveying good/bad news with it, So **you can use it** freely.

Comment: **Touch base** is an expression rather than an idiom, thought to originate from baseball and meaning **to get into contact** . (Expression: A word of phrase: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/expression) (Idiom: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/idiom)

Comment: @RonaldSole "Touch base" in its today usage is known as idiom and informal in most resources an dictionaries, I think what you say is possibly true but how about those resources?

Comment: The distinction that was raised in comments is misleading. Idioms *are* expressions. *Touch base* is both an expression *and* an idiom.

Comment: Touché! (Exclamation and expression!)